# Rails form get input value before submitting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I have a rails form which is separated in 3 steps, the first step is for the date selected, second step the time select and last step user info's.

Here is the form code :

```
<%= form_for [@school, Meeting.new], html: { id: 'meeting_form' } do |f| %>
    <!-- one step -->
    <div class="step">
        <section class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                   <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker1">
                    <%= f.text_field :date, class: 'form-control date_value', :required => true %>
                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                    </span>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
       </section>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary next-step" style="width: 100%;"> Suite </button>
 </div>
 <!-- end one step -->
 <!-- second step -->
 <div class="step">
    <section class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class='col-sm-6'>
             <div class="form-group">
               <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker2'>
                <%= f.hidden_field :mhour, required: true, class: "Vroomvroom-timepicker--value-js", :value => "" %>
                    <div class="scheduler--picker">
                        <% for time in 8..20 %>
                          <% if time < 10 %>
                            <div class="scheduler--picker-line-item <% if @school.meeting_already_booked?("0#{time}:00") %>scheduler--picker-line-item--disabled <% end %>" data-value="0<%= time %>:00">
                               <p>0<%= time %>:00</p>
                            </div>
                          <% else %>
                             <div class="scheduler--picker-line-item <% if @school.meeting_already_booked?("#{time}:00") %>scheduler--picker-line-item--disabled <% end %>" data-value="<%= time %>:00">
                             <p><%= time %>:00</p>
                             </div>
                           <% end %>
                         <% end %>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </section>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary previous-step" style="width: 49%;"> Retour </button>
           <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary next-step" style="width: 49%;"> Suite </button>
       </div>
     <!-- end second step -->
     <!-- third step -->
     <div class="step">
        <section class="container">
            <div class="row">
              <div class='col-sm-6' style="padding-left: 0;">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="name"> Nom </label>
                  <%= f.text_field :name, html: 'form-control', :required => true, placeholder: 'Votre nom de famille' %>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="firstname"> Prénom </label>
                  <%= f.text_field :firstname, html: 'form-control', :required => true, placeholder: 'Votre prénom' %>
               </div>
               <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="email"> Adresse email </label>
                  <%= f.email_field :email, html: 'form-control', :required => true, placeholder: 'Votre adresse mail, ex: jean.marc@gmail.com' %>
               </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                 <label for="phone"> Numéro de téléphone</label>
                 <%= f.text_field :phone, html: 'form-control', :required => true, placeholder: 'Votre numéro de téléphone, ex: 0606060606', :maxlength => 14 %>
               </div>
               <div class="form-group">
                 <label> Pour quel type de permis : </label>
                  <%= f.select :category do %>
                    <option value="code">Code uniquement</option>
                    <option value="moto">Permis A (moto)</option>
                    <option value="voiture">Permis B (voiture)</option>
                    <option value="am">Permis AM </option>
                 <option value="formation">Formations 125 cm3 </option>
                   <option value="autre">Une autre formation</option>
                  <% end %>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
         </section>
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary previous-step" style="width: 49%;"> Retour </button>
         <%= button_tag 'Envoyer', :type => :submit, :class => 'btn btn-primary end' %>
     </div>
    <!-- end thirs step -->
  <% end %>
```

for the date picker, I use bootstrap-datetimepicker for rails, but I create my own time picker, generated with div and data-attributes. I need to get the value of date before submitting the form to know which hours are already taken in DB to disable them.

I have created a method in the model School:

```
  # meetings
  def meeting_already_booked?(date, hour)
    if Meeting.where(:date => date).where(:time => hour)
      return true
    else
      return false
    end
  end
```

And I use the method here :

```
<div class="scheduler--picker-line-item <% if @school.meeting_already_booked?("0#{time}:00") %>Vroomvroom-scheduler--picker-line-item--disabled <% end %>" data-value="0<%= time %>:00">
```

I have the time, but I need the **date** that user selects the step just before to search in my DB if this hour is already taken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is to save the date locally on click of `next` button, something like

```
$("#next_step_button").on("click", function(event) {
  localStorage.setItem("date", $(#datetimepicker1).val());
});
```

To get the value back,

```
  localStorage.getItem("date");
```

Comment: Hey ! thank your for the answer, next I could use `localStorage.getItem("date");` in my html class ?

Comment: In the next step there might be an ajax call to `meeting_already_booked?` right? Use it there in javascript

Comment: Should you put an example of ajax call in my case ?